# Como puedo filtrar un resultado de un array de objetos en vuejs con laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Intento crear dos funciones para mouseover y mouseout, pero esta parte de vuejs me cuesta un poco de trabajo, esto tengo en mis funciones de vuejs, el que me interesa un poco mas es el **aespNew: this.aesp**

```
 import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

export default {
    components: {
        draggable
    },

    props: ['mSemestreI','mSemestreII','mSemestreIII', 'mSemestreIV', 'mSemestreV', 'mSemestreVI', 'mSemestreVII', 'mSemestreVIII', 'mSemestreIX','aesp'],

    data() {
        return{
            mSemestreINew: this.mSemestreI,
            mSemestreIINew: this.mSemestreII,
            mSemestreIIINew: this.mSemestreIII,
            mSemestreIVNew: this.mSemestreIV,
            mSemestreVNew: this.mSemestreV,
            mSemestreVINew: this.mSemestreVI,
            mSemestreVIINew: this.mSemestreVII,
            mSemestreVIIINew: this.mSemestreVIII,
            mSemestreIXNew: this.mSemestreIX,
            aespNew: this.aesp,
            btn: 'primary'
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onAdd(event, posx){
            let id = event.item.getAttribute('data-id');
            axios.patch('/materias/updatePosx/' + id, {
                posx: posx
            }).then((response)=>{
                //success message
            })
        },
        update(){
            this.mSemestreINew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreIINew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreIIINew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreIVNew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreVNew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreVINew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreVIINew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreVIIINew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })

            this.mSemestreIXNew.map((posy,index) => {
                posy.posy = index + 1
            })


            let posy = this.mSemestreINew.concat(this.mSemestreIINew).concat(this.mSemestreIIINew).concat(this.mSemestreIVNew).concat(this.mSemestreVNew).concat(this.mSemestreVINew).concat(this.mSemestreVIINew).concat(this.mSemestreVIIINew).concat(this.mSemestreIXNew);

            axios.put('/materias/updateAll', {
                posy: posy
            }).then((response) => {
                //success message
            })
        },
        mouseOver: function(index){
            let mover = this.aespNew;
            console.log(mover);
            this.active = true;
        },
        mouseOut:function(){
            console.log('false');
            this.active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

la parte del Log me arroja esto haciendo esto `console.log(mover);`

[image: Log de aespnew]

A final de cuentas tomare ese `area_especial_id` para hacer un hover a un elemento draggable (cambiar color)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito:

Script a traducir:

```
 $('#<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>').mouseover(function(){

$(".<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>").css("background-color", "<?echo $trayectoria->getColor(); ?>");

$(".<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>").css("color", "white");

                                    });
$('#<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>').mouseout(function(){
 $(".<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>").css("background-color", "white");
                                        $(".<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>").css("color", "black");
                                    });

   //De materias a trayectorias
 $('.<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>').mouseover(function(){

   $("#<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>").css("transform", "scale(1.2)");
                                    });
 $('.<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>').mouseout(function(){
 $("#<?echo $listaTrayectoria->getIdAreaEspecialidad();?>").css("transform", "scale(1)");
});
<?}?>
```

lo que he logrado hasta ahorita es hacer el hover de color pero manualmente pero solo con la lista, me falta ligar los botones con las listas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No estás mostrando el template por lo que no sabemos cómo estás insertando el draggable en el template. El warn que te aparece es porque [en la versión 2.20 cambió la sintaxis](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/documentation/migrate.md#options-props).

La librería subyacente (draggable.js) recibe [opciones que determinan el comportamiento del conjunto ordenable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options). Por ejemplo, si declaras el tiempo de la animación, y la clase de la "manilla" desde donde agarras cada cajita:

```
{
  animation:150, 
  handle:'.manilla'
}
```

En la sintaxis anterior de Vue.sortable, el componente se declaraba como:

```
<draggable v-for="list" :options="{animation:150, handle:'.manilla'}">
  <!-- -->
</draggable>
```

Ahora esas opciones se pasan transparentemente al componente:

```
<draggable v-for="list" :animation="150" :handle=".manilla">
  <!-- -->
</draggable>
```

Pero también creo que tienes otro problema, y es que estás usando mal el concepto de Array.prototype.map.

Si lo que quieres es reasignar la propiedad "posy" de cada elemento, tienes que retornar el elemento modificado.

Por ejeplo

```
 let arrayDePosiciones = [{posy:0},{posy:1},{posy:2}];
 arrayDePosiciones = arrayDePosiciones.map((elemento,index)=>{
    elemento.posy = index+1;
    return elemento; // <--- esto 
 });
 // resultado es [{posy:1},{posy:2},{posy:3}]
```

La iteración que haces ahora no retorna nada, así que la salida de

```
  this.mSemestreINew.map((posy,index) => {
     posy.posy = index + 1
  })
```

Sería `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

(Pero en tu caso es inofensivo porque tampoco estás reasignando la salida a `this.mSemestreINew`

Comment: Bien pero ahorita posy esta funcionando bien ya que hago un cambio de posicion y lo registro en la base de datos, lo que necesito es realizar o tomar un valor de lo que me arroja la funcion mouseOver, como acceder solo al area_esepcialidad_id de cada boton, edito lo que tengo

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer. El componente que muestras dibuja los semestres y los botones? La idea es que cada botón es una asignatura y al pasar el mouse sobre ellos se resalta ésta en los semestres donde figure?

Comment: Exacto, Por ejemplo los botones llevan un ID con nombre area_especialidad_id, y los elementos de la lista tambien llevan ese id (para referenciarlos) entonces cuando pase el mouse sobre el boton por ejemplo id = 10, los elementos de la lista con referencia al id 10, se coloreen o hagan el hover, tengo el script en JS pero necesito pasarlo a vue, edito la pregunta

Comment: Mira, mejor haz otra pregunta, porque mi respuesta sirve para entender el warning. Asegúrate te poner el código con que dibujas los botones y semestres (el template o html que tengas). Y explícanos el propósito del método update, porque no entiendo qué quieres hacer aumentando los posy

Comment: la parte de posy y posx es solamente para el ordenamiento de la Malla, cordenadas X y Y, como te indique estoy usando Draggable

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310207/como-podria-traducir-este-script-a-vuejs-laravel y apenas hice esta otra ya un poco mas especifico